# Rails App Movies API - Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, api, postgresql, heroku

I have a Rails Movie App which will potentially use APIs from other websites to fill my database.

I am using the TMDB.org API (I already have an API Key) to extract, for now lets say the ***Title*** and ***Description*** of a movie.

How would I go by extracting information from the tmdb site to my site and display the information in `<% @movie.title %>` and `<% @movie.description %>`
The information taken will need to be placed in my **PostgreSQL** Database using **Heroku**
So thats one question

The other question is how would I do this without running a method for every movie in the TMDB database

For Example, using the [Ruby-TMDB Gem](https://github.com/aarongough/ruby-tmdb), instead of running

```
TmdbMovie.find(:title => "The Social Network", :limit => 10, :expand_results => true, :language => "en")
```

and

```
TmdbMovie.find(:title => "The Dark Knight Rises ", :limit => 10, :expand_results => true, :language => "en")
```

for every movie I want in my database (which is every movie in the TMDB Database), what would I run to `GET` ALL Movies.

And then Display them in my movies *:show* page

To sum it all up, how to I get database information from TMDB.org to my rails app and display information from a TMDB Movie *:show* page to my movie *:show* page, using the [Ruby-TMDB Gem](https://github.com/aarongough/ruby-tmdb) IN Heroku? Would there be a rake task, if so what would it be?

Many Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 problems you wish to tackle.

***How and where in my rails app should I pull the data?***

Yeah this can be accomplished with rake. Add a new rake file `lib/tasks/tmdb.rake`

```
namespace :db do
  task :pull_tmdb_data => :environment do

    Tmdb.api_key = "t478f8de5776c799de5a"
    # setup your default language
    Tmdb.default_language = "en"

    # find movies by id
    @movie = TmdbMovie.find(id: 123)
    Movie.create title: @movie.title, description: @movie.description

    # find movies in groups
    @movies = TmdbMovie.find(:title => 'Iron Man')
    @movies.each do |movie|
        Movie.create title: movie.title, description: movie.description
    end

  end
end
```

And now everytime you want to populate your db with tmdb you can simply run `rake db:pull_tmdb_data`

***What are the necessary queries to pull all the movies from tmdb?***

By glancing over their api there is no shortcut to duplicating the database, if you want to duplicate it your best bet may be to contact them directly. You can brute force it by trying every possible id for movies but beware that they do throttle you. Below is a quote from their website.

*We do enforce a small amount of rate limiting. Please be aware that should you exceed these limits, you will receive a 503 error.*

- *30 requests every 10 seconds per IP*
- *Maximum 20 simultaneous
  connections*

It may be worth considering if you really need to duplicate tmdb. When tmdb is adding new movies and fixing errors in their data your database will be outdated as a result you will face a slew of data integrity issues which will be hard to resolve.

Comment: You could try searching for an empty title and see what that returns ```@movies = TmdbMovie.find(:title => '')```

Comment: Sorry Im awfully new to Rails so I have a few Questions

Comment: namespace is that just namespace or is it the name of the app or controller it'll be working with (movies)?

Comment: # get form tmdb   What would go there? Say my API Key is 123456789, how would it look

Comment: # here you have access to your models   What does this mean, I know what the model is but would I need to input anything there

Comment: Movie.create title: data[:title] ....
          If I were to have multiple items, such as title and description  how would it go

Comment: namespace refers to where we're adding the new task. In this case we're adding it to the :db namespace. so you run as ```rake db:pull_tmdb_data```.

Comment: Ok thanks that seems like it should work, I'll test it out when I get to my computer. One quick thing though, find(id: 123) What is this? it's not the tmdb movie Id is it? As I am looking for multiple movies at once I don't think it'll work

Comment: Yes, it was querying movies by id, but you can easily look for multiple movies by title, as I've shown in the updated example above. Look at ruby-tmdb github page which you linked to figure out how to structure the query to your liking.

Comment: This is where I dont understand your answer. In the question it states I will be searching for multiple movies, how would this work ? Your saying to search for title with id 123 or by title 'IRON MAN' 

When i run this code, I wont be providing a title or an id, ill expect for the api to fetch all movies whatever their name and add them to my db

Comment: how are you going to fetch all the movies? What is the exact api query? Unless you go id by id I don't see a way to retrieve all the movies.Keep in mind they enforce a request limit. You can try searching for an empty title as I mentioned in the first comment, it may work.

Comment: When I run rake db:pull_tmdb_data, nothing happens

Comment: heroku run rake db:pull_tmdb_data

Comment: did you try it locally first?

Comment: Yes. And still, nothing happens?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32222/discussion-between-omarshammas-and-pmp)

Comment: My problem now is that it doesnt save the found movie in the database, i can find a movie using the rake command, but it doesnt save it to the datbase

Comment: Well when i go to local host or my heroku app, I cant see the movie listed